# Adding all the non-coprimes to $n$ smaller than $n$ as fast as possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that you want to calculate the sum of all the numbers between $1$ and $n$ that are not coprime $n$. How would you do this by hand in under one minute if $n$ was under $10,000$ and you had access to a table of primes and a calculator?

Comment: Why do I feel like the part of title that's in parentheses is way more important than the part that isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia states that
$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\ (k,n) = 1}} k = \frac{1}{2} n \varphi(n),
$$
for $n > 1$. You are actually interested in
$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\ (k,n) \neq 1}} k = \frac{n}{2} (n+1 - \varphi(n)),
$$
again for $n > 1$. Euler's function $\varphi(n)$ has a simple expression in terms of the factorization of $n$.

Comment: Oh wow, this took me like half an hour.

Comment: You didn't consult Wikipedia.

Comment: hahaha, yeah, it might be worth pointing out the first equality can be seen by pairing up $k$ and $(n-k)$ which are both coprime to $n$ if one of them is.

Answer (score 2):

A number is not coprime to $n$ iff it has a common factor with $n$, so it's enough to (1) find the prime factorization of $n$ and (2) find the number of numbers $\leq n$ with one of those primes as a factor.

Now, if $n$ has a single prime factor $p$, then
$$\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq n \\ (i,n) \neq 1}} i = \sum_{j = 1}^{n / p} jp = p \sum_{j = 1}^{n / p} j = p \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{n}{p} \left(\frac{n}{p} + 1\right) = \frac{1}{2} n \left(\frac{n}{p} + 1\right).$$ If we write $n = p^m$, this is
$$\frac{1}{2} p^m (p^{m - 1} + 1).$$ If $n$ is itself prime, that is, if $m = 1$ so that $n = p$, this sum is of course just $n$ itself.

For general $n$, say, with prime factors $p_1, \ldots, p_r$, we can simply add the above expression for each $p_k$, compensating for double-counting using the inclusion-exclusion principle; after factoring, the general formula is
$$\frac{1}{2} n \sum_{k = 1}^r \sum_{p_{l_1} \leq \cdots \leq p_{l_k}} (-1)^{k + 1} \left(\frac{n}{p_{l_1} \cdots p_{l_k}} + 1\right).$$ (This counts $n$ itself in the sum; of course, it is easy to exclude $n$, simply by subtracting it from the final sum.) Now, an easy argument with the binomial theorem shows that the total contribution from the $\pm 1$'s is just $1$, so the formula simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2} n \left(1 + \sum_{k = 1}^r \sum_{p_{l_1} \leq \cdots \leq p_{l_k}} (-1)^{k + 1} \frac{n}{p_{l_1} \cdots p_{l_k}}\right).$$
If $n = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$, we can write this as
$$\frac{1}{2} n \left(1 + p_1^{a_1 - 1} \cdots p_r^{a_r - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{r - 1} \sum_{p_{l_1} \leq \cdots \leq p_{l_k}} (-1)^{r - k + 1} p_{l_1} \cdots p_{l_k}\right) = \frac{1}{2} n \left(1 + p_1^{a_1 - 1} \cdots p_r^{a_r - 1} [(p_1 \cdots p_r) - (p_1 - 1) \cdots (p_r - 1)]\right).$$

In practice this is easy to execute once one has the prime factorization in hand. Some examples using randomly generated integers $n \leq 10^4$:

- $n = 5861$ is prime, so it is its only prime factor, and the formula gives
  $$\frac{1}{2} (5861) (1 + 1) = 5861$$
  as expected.
- $n = 6506 = 2 \cdot 3253$. The formula gives
  $$\frac{1}{2}(6506) [1 + (2 \cdot 3253 - 1 \cdot 3252)] = (3253)(3255) = 10588515.$$ More generally, for a product $p_1 p_2$ of two distinct primes, the sum is
  $\frac{1}{2} p_1 p_2 (p_1 + p_2)$.
- $n = 1204 = 2^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 43$. The formula gives
  $$\frac{1}{2}(1204) [1 + 2 (2 \cdot 7 \cdot 43 - 1 \cdot 6 \cdot 42)] = (602) (701) = 422002.$$

The last example is typical in the sense that the average number of distinct prime divisors for $n \leq 10^4$ is $2.43$. On the other hand, most numbers are square free ($6083$ among $n \leq 10^4$, very close to the asymptotic proportion of $\frac{\pi^2}{6} \sim 60.79\%$), and it is precisely for these numbers that $p_1^{a_1 - 1} \cdots p_r^{a_r - 1} = 1$, simplifying the last formula

Comment: Oh, this is impressive, although it might take some time to calculate. Another way is to sum the coprime numbers and then substract this from the total sum of numbers between $1$ and $n$. The total sum is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. The sum of the comprimes is $\frac{\varphi(n)n}{2}$. This is because if $k$ is coprime to $n$ then so is $n-k$. So pairing every comprime number $k$ with $n-k$ we get that the sum is equal to $\varphi(n)/2*n$

Comment: Yes, but of course that involves actually computing $\varphi(n)$ in the first place, which is tantamount to doing the kind of computation done in this answer! (Also, I replaced the double sum with a difference of easy products, which should improve computation time quite a lot for numbers with large numbers of prime factors.)

Comment: (Conversely, you can tweak this answer just a little bit to produce an explicit formula for $\varphi(n)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$.)